# SSDT and Amazon RDS migration issue

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, sql-server-data-tools, amazon-rds

I have a problem with Amazon RDS SQL Server (2014) and trying to use it with Visual Studio SQL Server Data Tools, and there's not much in the way of help on the AWS support site.

I have run up an instance of RDS with and accessed it with SQL Management Studio with no problems. I create a database and then run a schema compare from SSDT and hit update.

The first thing the update process does is amends the db_owner authorisation which then completely locks out the master user from the database on RDS. The change is identified when you hit compare in SSDT, but there is no way of turning it off that I can see.

Can anyone tell me a way around the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the SchemaCompareProject page click on the sttings icon and go to the Object Types tab. Within the Application-scoped list there is an option for Role Memberships.

Uncheck this and re-run the compare - the line item forcing the change of authorisation disappears. This keeps rdsa as the db_owner and everything syncs correctly.

Comment: In general, you'll want to be careful with role memberships, users, permissions granted directly to users, and logins. Those tend to differ between environments and MS has yet to provide a good way to handle those different environments out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

If you want it to stop deploying permissions I wrote this for an environment where I wasn't dbo and the same thing kept happening:

http://agilesqlclub.codeplex.com/

IgnoreSecurity will stop you hurting yourself.

Ed

Comment: Hi Ed, it'd be great to know what you wrote!

Comment: -2 because I didn't post the full comment by mistakes, how mean! :) It should be there now!

Comment: Lol I didn't think so!

Comment: Thanks for the response but I found unchecking Role Memberships worked for me.